# NFS reporting clientid is in use

Tags: 14.04, networking, nfs

Two weeks ago, our network switched around and since then I've had issues with a workstation. It was originally configured as a static IP and now it is switched to DHCP. The home directory is an NFS mount and the users are on a NIS server. With no change to the `fstab` file from what was there before, and what is in every other workstation, the home directories are not usable although it does show the correct permissions for users. However, when logging in, I get:

```
-bash: /home_net/<username>/.bash_profile: Operation not permitted
```

and when trying to `touch` a file I get:

```
touch: setting times of ‘temp’: No such file or directory
```

lastly, when I look through `dmesg` I see:

```
[   58.728507] nfs: server <server> OK
[   58.733960] NFS: Server <server> reports our clientid is in use
[   58.733965] NFS: state manager: lease expired failed on NFSv4 server <server> with error 1
```

I've checked the system clock and it seems to match the server. I've checked the `fstab` and it matches every other functional workstations'.

What the heck is wrong with this thing? And why does the NFS say my clientid is in use? Why does my NFS drive mount and show the correct permissions but then not actually work?

Comment: What's the difference in file rights between this WS and other WSs? (did this user use a bit too much `sudo`???

Answer (score 1):

We encountered similar symptoms during an update of a commercial NFS server.

Very possibly during the network changes the server and client got out of sync. The server is not accepting any file operation requests.  There have been a number of bug fixes in this area. You didn't mention which version of NFS client you're using or what NFS server, but keeping those packages up to date is a good idea.

Try unmounting and re-mounting /home.